# m3u8 file contents order

Tags: video-streaming, m3u8

I have a m3u8 file and was wondering if it matters which order the files/urls are in.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=450000,RESOLUTION=448x252
448x252_450.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=800000,RESOLUTION=624x352
624x352_800.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1200000,RESOLUTION=640x360
640x360_1200.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1800000,RESOLUTION=640x360
640x360_1800.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2600000,RESOLUTION=1280x720
1280x720_2600.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=125000,CODECS="mp4a.40.2"
mp4a.40.2.m3u8
```

If you notice, the RESOLUTIONs aren't in lowest to highest. That is what I'm concerned about.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Only the first #EXT-X-STREAM-INF matters. It will be be chosen as the first stream to load. Once a couple segments are downloaded and the player has a good idea about bandwidth available, it will choose from the rest of the list.

Comment: I did that, but the video is always playing on the smallest resolution. Any idea why it isnt bumping up to the next resolution?

Comment: It only plays what I have listed first.

Answer (score 0):

Which HLS player are you using?

The order of the URLs does not matter. Typically a HLS player downloads the first / lowest resolution initially and then constantly monitors the throughput of each transport stream download to determine the bandwidth available.